# Why should I use const T& instead of const T or T&

Tags: c++

I always use `const T&` to pass a class to a function. Like this:

```
void foo(const MyType& p)
{
  //...
}
```

But now I'm confused, why not pass a `const T` or a `T&` to a function?

By the way, for built-in types, like `int`, `long long`, `double`, why `const T` is better than `const T&` <del>(I remember I've read in *Effective C++*)</del>

Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: Because they are different things? Reference: yes or no. Const: yes or no. Pick what you need and there ya go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pass any of the three (*const T, T&,* or *const T&*). They all have different meanings. Up to you whether you want to pass a copy of the object that cannot be modified, a non-const reference to the object, or a const reference to the object. What you choose depends on the semantics of your code. Overall, you would want to choose `const T&` over `const T` in order to refrain from having to copy the value over from the caller to this function (save time and memory). Moreover (according to [this helpful link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html)), you would want to use `const T&` over `T&` whenever you want to refrain from changing neither the *value* nor the *state* of the passed reference. This can prevent silly and overlooked coding errors, such as changing a field for testing purposes.

For your question about passing as a parameter a reference to a const primitive type, see this: [C++ and QT4.5 - is passing a const int& overkill? Does pass by reference helps in signals/slots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333176/c-and-qt4-5-is-passing-a-const-int-overkill-does-pass-by-reference-helps-i)

Comment: You should add T&& to your list

Comment: It's an R-value reference.  Added in c++11.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors or http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

Comment: YIPPEE!!! My first accepted answer. Thanks guys (and I hope I didn't break any rules by sharing my excitement...)

Answer (score 1):

const T is passed by value (copy is needed), which may be too much for a class while should be ok for built-in types.

T& is passed by reference, which could be modified in the function while const T& can't, so it depends on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

> (I remember I've read in Effective C++)

No, you don't, because Scott Meyers wouldn't make such a mistake.

`const T&` is the best option because it never involves a copy but can still take rvalues. Consider

```
void foo(int& p);
void foo(const std::string s);
int main() { 
    foo(1); // illegal!
    foo("A reaaaaaaaallllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllly long string");
    // Nasty copy
}
```

If you need a copy of an item, make one in the parameter list (take by value) but there's little reason for this value to be `const`. Else, use `const T&`. For some cheap types there's little point not taking by value because you know in advance that copying is cheap.

Comment: Stroustrup himself basically said that [here](http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#pointers-and-references). See the *Should I use call-by-value or call-by-reference?* section. Of course I presume that FAQ is fairly old now (when the answer was written, not when the FAQ was last modified), and now we have move constructors, too, which also skews it a bit.

Comment: Oh, maybe it's not _Effective C++_, sorry. Thanks for help

Comment: @DeadMG Today I read _Effective C++_ again, and I found it at Chapter 4 Item 20. You could see the picture: https://twitter.com/abcdabcd987/status/231961897145081856/photo/1

Answer (score 0):

Your rule to always pass by const reference is overly general.

Passing by const reference generally indicates that

- the method is not going to modify the argument
- that the method may not claim ownership of the argument
- that the caller guarantees the
  argument's lifetime will be longer than the call

If you need something different, then you should choose something other than passing by const reference.